# Handling multitouch in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

In ***flutter***, there is a standard ***GestureDetector*** that allows to interprets  the commands ***"touch down"***, ***"touch move"*** and ***"touch up"*** by means of the corresponding handlers:

- onPanStart: _handlePanStart,
- onPanUpdate: _handlePanUpdate,
- onPanEnd: _handlePanEnd,

However, we are talking about processing a single touch, but what if I want to handle several parallel touches and movements? I.e. really use multitouch? Is there any kind of built-in control in flutter (maybe multitouch gesture detector, I don't known) that allows to get a vector or a list of events of clicks, movements, ups with ids of touches and their current coordinates?

Comment: see `Listener` class (and its `onPointer*` properties) or you simply need `GestureDetector#onScale*` properties?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are looking for [MultiDragGestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/MultiDragGestureRecognizer-class.html). Look into [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11600) to know more.

Edit : There is no direct widget that you can use. You'll need to create a StatefulWidget that instantiates the MultiDragGestureRecognizer, then have your build function have a Listener that routes the onPointerDown event to the recognizer.