# Flutter multiple finger press events

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, mobile-development

I'm currently experimenting with Flutter and its abilities. I found this app [Chwazi Finger Chooser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tendadigital.chwaziApp&hl=en_GB) on the Google Play Store.

This app allows the users to put multiple fingers on a blank screen, a circle is drawn around each finger and then one is selected.

- Does Flutter have the ability for multiple finger presses at the same time like this app?
- And for the location of that press to be shared so that a circle may be drawn around that press?

I don't want people to just do this for me, I'm just wondering really if anyone has tried this sort of thing before in Flutter. Seeking advice as still a novice.

[image: App Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [multitouch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/MultiDragGestureRecognizer-class.html) feature in Flutter.

Read more here: [Handling multitouch in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514596/handling-multitouch-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar, here is some code:

```
RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: {
        MultiTapGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<MultiTapGestureRecognizer>(
          () => MultiTapGestureRecognizer(),
          (MultiTapGestureRecognizer instance) {
            instance.onTapDown =(pointer, details) {
              log( 'X=${details.localPosition.dx}  Y=${details.localPosition.dy}' )
            };
          },  
        ),
      },
      child:
        ...some content widget here,
    )
)
```