# Is there any way to detect multiple touches on my screeen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listener, tap, gesturedetector

I have this piece of code and what it does is when touching on the screen a blue circle appears and follows the tap/drag location of my finger . What i want to achive is to have this blue circle appear each time theres a new finger on the screen even if there are 2 or 3 touches at the same time. 
Please Help me I am totally stuck.
I tried to add more than one onpointerdown event but thats a bad idea.

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new SecondScreenState();
}


class SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  GlobalKey _paintKey = new GlobalKey();
  Offset _offset;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: new Text('Choosing..',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50,
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body:
            GestureDetector(

                child: Listener(

                    onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent event) {
                      RenderBox referenceBox = _paintKey.currentContext
                          .findRenderObject();
                      Offset offset = referenceBox.globalToLocal(
                          event.position);
                      setState(() {
                        _offset = offset;
                      });
                    },

                    onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {

                    },


                    onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent event) {
                      setState(() {
                        _offset = null;
                      });
                    },

                    child: new CustomPaint(
                      key: _paintKey,
                      painter: new MyCustomPainter(_offset),
                      child: new ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
                      )
                      ,
                    )
                )
    )
    );



  }
}

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset _offset;
  MyCustomPainter(this._offset);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (_offset == null) return;
    canvas.drawCircle(_offset, 100.0, new Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCustomPainter other) => other._offset != _offset;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling multitouch in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514596/handling-multitouch-in-flutter)

Comment: check `PointerEvent.pointer` property

Answer (score 0):

You can use ready made solution( I used it previously)
https://pub.dev/packages/touch_indicator
And also you can check source code and grab widget to your project
https://github.com/Mardaneus86/touch_indicator/blob/master/lib/touch_indicator.dart